# Should a boolean active column in an Objects table have a default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just created an `active` boolean column in a `relationships` table and I was wondering if the column having a default `true` value is a good practice, or if it's best if it was initially left as a `nil` value?

This is the `schema.rb` file.

```
  ... 

  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "active",      default: true
  end

  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always good practice to set a default value(`true`/`false`) in boolean column adding migration. You should avoid `NULL` in boolean columns.

Without setting default value this migration

```
add_column :relationships, :active, :boolean
```

will generate three state boolean problem. Your `active` boolean column supposed to be only `true` or `false` but it can be `true`, `false`, or `NULL` and this query

`SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE relationships.active = FALSE`

will not give you the results you expect since `NULL` is not equal to `FALSE`

You can read more about it here([ref1](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/avoid-the-threestate-boolean-problem), [ref2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133600/should-i-store-false-as-null-in-a-boolean-database-field))

Answer (score 1):

having default value to boolean is  good practice so that there is no need to set it as active manually, in your case when you create relationships.